# Position a hidden box into a focused input with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am wondering how to place a hidden box div into an input text that is currently in focus?

```
        <input type="text" class="target" name="some_name">
        <input type="text" class="target" name="other_name">
        <input type="text" class="target" name="another_name">
        <input type="text" class="target" name="some_other_name">

        other HTML ....


        <div id="hidden">This div is hidden somewhere in the page, 
    and only visible if any of the above input text is in focus. 
    Once another input is in focus, this box is moved 
relatively positioned (next, top or bottom) to the focus input. 
    This should be hidden if no input is in focus.</div>
```

I notice a plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/
but no idea if that is what I need at all.

Any hint or direction is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...place a hidden box div into an input text...

`input` elements cannot have child elements, so you can't put it *inside* in the DOM sense. You could put it on top of the input, e.g.:

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    $("#hidden")
        .data("showing-for", this.name)
        .css({
            position: "absolute",
            left:     pos.left + "px",
            top:      pos.top + "px"
        })
        .show();
}).blur(function() {
    var hidden = $("#hidden");
    if (hidden.data("showing-for") === this.name) {
        hidden.hide();
    }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ulipug)

There we're using [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) to get the position of the focussed input and then positioning the "hidden" `div` on top of it and showing it; on `blur` we hide it again. We use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to remember which input the div is showing for so we only hide it when we see the correct `blur` (just being defensive).

(Note that I've assumed the `id` value on the `div` will be `"hidden"`, not `"#hidden"` as in your HTML example. You don't write the hash mark (`#`) in the `id` attribute, that's just the CSS indicator that what *follows* is an `id` in a selector.)

Comment: Thanks. Will have a test now. I have clarified my question, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I modified to $("input.target")...., but the hidden div is replacing my input text with the class "target". Maybe I missed something

Comment: Hmm, my problem is those inputs are placed within many fieldsets, other divs, and form items. Not actually replacing, but hidden div position is not good: 
element.style {
    display: none; /*this changed to block on focus, good*/
    left: 494.767px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1029.68px;
}

Comment: Thanks. I moved the hidden div far beyond all its wrapping parents, and works like the demo. Thank you very much